# Spring MessageSource find by several locales

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

I have following case: I'm getting a list of locales from mobile and I need to check my MessageSource whether it has any matches with the passed list. So by default, I can check by one locale and if spring doesn't find a match it will use default locale but in my case, I need to check the list of locales. Is there any support for this feature in spring?

Comment: `I need to check my MessageSource whether it has any matches. `

If you are looking for all the supported locales by server then you can use `Locale.getAvailableLocales()`

Comment: I need to get all available locales which were resolved by spring.

Comment: I don't think there is any API or method from where we can get all the resolved locales from spring. I think we can try all the locales with message in MesssageSource in the order of priority. If message is not translated then return default message. Internally a hashmap is maintained for each message and locale, so it would not impact performance also.

Comment: can you please provide some example? not sure I understood your suggestion

Comment: or probably you mean to try to get n times to get message from MessageSource?

Comment: yeah, iterating over the list received from the mobile and trying for each locale.

Comment: that was one of my first solutions - but I hope there should be cleaner way how to do that in spring...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it in following way:

```java
    @Bean
    public CustomMessageSource messageSource() {
        CustomReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new CustomReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }


    public class CustomReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource extends
    ResourceBundleMessageSource implements CustomMessageSource {
    public String getMessage(String code, List<Locale> locales) {
        return locales.stream().map(locale -> getMessage(code, null, locale))
            .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty).findFirst()
            .orElse(getMessage(code, null, Locale.ENGLISH));
    }
}
```

Setting **fallbackToSystemLocale** property to false was pretty important because otherwise system used default locale for each unresolved message.

Comment: this is not a good answer, if the first locale can't be found then a NoSuchMessageException will be returned. Should catch the exception and return null when calling getMessage(code, null, locale)